# jquery showing AND hidding a notification - Notyfy

Tags: jquery, css, noty

I am new to jquery. I am using the [Notyfy](http://craga89.github.io/notyfy/) jQuery plugin. I want to show the notification bar with the message on specific condition. want to show the success and error message on specific condition

I want to do something like this. please correct my code so I can successfully implement this library

```
var notyfy-success = notyfy({text: 'successfully deleted'});
var notyfy-error = notyfy({text: 'somethings wrong'});
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (true){
    alert("hello");
         notyfy-success.show('success bar ');
    }else{
         notyfy-error.show('error bar ');
    }   
});
```

Comment: where are you getting the if (true){ value from, whats the response your getting at the moment? simply place say notyfy({text: 'successfully deleted'}); outside of the if statement to ensure it is being called? have a look at the browsers console to see what if any feedback your getting?

Comment: well its just a sample to show that what i want to do.. if condition is working correctly i am checking through by alerting hello .. so i wanted to know is that a right method to show a notfy bar .. because it is not working on my side.. i am showing the message by writing this code notyfy-success.show(); which isn't working

Comment: not a problem, its just if(true) means nothing as WHATS true??

Comment: it means nothing. it just i want to explain that if the condition is true do this. you can say pseudo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **TRUE** in if() condition the else script never be performed. (buy i think u know that). However...
I see the Documentation of the plugin and you not need to instantiate `notyfy-success` and `notyfy-error` define them only (**TAKE CARE** the character `-` inside a variable name is not a good idea, use `_`), and then inside "if" statement instantiates them:

```
var _delete = true, //is the returned value of a action that delate somethig set to  "false" and try
notyfy_success, notyfy_error;
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (_delete){
         notyfy_success = notyfy({text: 'successfully deleted'});
    }else{
         notyfy_error = notyfy({text: 'somethings wrong'});
    }   
});
```

Now, on document ready the **notyfy_success** notification will show, if you set `_delete` to `false` **notyfy_error** will show instead **notyfy_success**.

http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/43C7Q/

**OMG... my english is terrible... I'm so sorry. I hope you can understand.. my bad.**

Comment: ;) I'm glad to have help.